# Creating rows as per duration using datetime pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am facing an issue to write a code using datetime. I had created a scenario I am working on. Can someone help me out on the code.

**Input:**

```
Name, Channel, Duration, Start_time
John, A, 2, 16:00:00
Joseph, B, 3, 15:05:00
```

**Output:**

```
Name, Channel, Duration, Start_time
John, A, 2, 16:00:00
John, A, 2, 16:01:00
Joseph, B, 3, 15:05:00
Joseph, B, 3, 15:06:00
Joseph, B, 3, 15:07:00
```

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df['Start_time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Start_time'])
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Duration'])]
td = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() * 60, unit='s')

df['Start_time'] = df['Start_time'] + td
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print (df)
     Name Channel  Duration Start_time
0    John       A         2   16:00:00
1    John       A         2   16:01:00
2  Joseph       B         3   15:05:00
3  Joseph       B         3   15:06:00
4  Joseph       B         3   15:07:00
```

**Explanation**:

1. Firt convert column `Start_time` [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html)
2. Then [`repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.repeat.html) values of index by column `Duration` and repeat rows by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)
3. Create counter by [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) per index values and convert it to 1 minute timedeltas, which are added to new repeated column `Start_time`
4. Last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with parameter `drop=True` for avoid duplicated index values

EDIT:

If want datetimes in output solution is same, only first convert values [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
df['Start_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start_time'])
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['Duration'])]
td = pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount() * 60, unit='s')

df['Start_time'] = df['Start_time'] + td
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
     Name Channel  Duration          Start_time
0    John       A         2 2018-11-19 16:00:00
1    John       A         2 2018-11-19 16:01:00
2  Joseph       B         3 2018-11-19 15:05:00
3  Joseph       B         3 2018-11-19 15:06:00
4  Joseph       B         3 2018-11-19 15:07:00
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the previous answer. Need one more small help. If I have to summarize the input data i mentioned into half an hour bands. Like my output looks-like,        Name, Channel, Duration, Timeband, Duration, count
John, A, 2, 16:00:00-16:30:00 1
Joseph, B, 3, 15:00:00-15:30:00 1................... We may face an issue when we summarize a row with duration 10 watching which will split between bands like 5 minutes in 15:00:00-15:30:00 and other 5 minutes in 15:30:00-16:00:00.

Comment: @SrikanthAyithy - Only one answer should be accepting, can you check it?

Comment: @SrikanthAyithy - Thank you. To your question in comments - Can you create another one question?

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
df['dates'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(pd.date_range(start=x['Start_time'], periods=x['Duration'], freq='1min')), axis=1)
df.set_index(['Name','Channel','Duration', 'Start_time'])['dates'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index().drop(['level_4','Start_time'],1).rename(columns={0:'Start_time'})
```

**Output**

```
    Name    Channel Duration    Start_time
0   John    A   3   2018-11-19 16:00:00
1   John    A   3   2018-11-19 16:01:00
2   John    A   3   2018-11-19 16:02:00
3   Joseph  B   4   2018-11-19 15:05:00
4   Joseph  B   4   2018-11-19 15:06:00
5   Joseph  B   4   2018-11-19 15:07:00
6   Joseph  B   4   2018-11-19 15:08:00
```

**Explanation**

1. Apply `pd.date_range()` to `Start_time` and `Duration`
2. explode that into a `df` with the second line

Comment: This is working too. However, results are going into one row.